# Shortest Path (BFS) through a maze

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, pathfinding, breadth-first-search

### Background

I have decided to use this year's Advent Of Code to learn Haskell. I feel like I vaguely understand the language and can solve most of the problems with relative ease. However, the code I produce is not the most readable and possibly has inefficiencies. Any suggestions on how to improve **readability** and **performance** would be much appreciated.

### [Problem](http://adventofcode.com/2016/day/13)

The problem is Day 13 of AoC. It consists of a maze where each cell `(x,y)` is either a wall or an empty space, dictated by the population count of the following equation:

```
x*x + 3*x + 2*x*y + y + y*y + key (where key is some arbitrary integer)
```

The cell is a wall if the population count is odd. The problem then comes in two parts:

1. Find shortest distance between `(1,1)` and `(31,39)`.
2. Find number of cells that can be visited in 50 or less steps (from `(1,1)`).

### [Code](https://github.com/Norfavrell/adventofcode-16/blob/master/day13/day13.hs)

The code uses BFS for both parts. I am aware that A* may quicker for Part1.

```
import Data.Bits (popCount)
import qualified Data.Map as Map 
import Debug.Trace 

-- Define all types 
type Index = (Int, Int)                         -- (x,y)
type Edges = [Index]                            -- list of connecting edges
type Prob  = (Int, Int, Int)                    -- (key, width, height)
type State = (Index, Int, Map.Map Index Bool)   -- (current, steps, visited)

-- Determine if a specific cell index represents a wall
isWall :: Int -> Index -> Bool 
isWall key (x,y) = odd $ popCount num 
    where num = x*x+3*x+2*x*y+y+y*y+key


-- Generate all edges of a specific cell
mkEdges :: Int -> Index -> Edges 
mkEdges key (x,y) = filter (not.isWall key) adjs
    where adjs = wB [(x, y-1), (x+1, y), (x,y+1), (x-1,y)]
          wB   = filter (\(a,b) -> not (a<0 || b<0))

-- Find the shortest path length 
bfsPathLength :: Int -> Index -> [State] -> Int 
bfsPathLength key goal t@((curr, steps, visited):rest)  | goal==curr = steps
                                                        | otherwise  = bfsPathLength key goal newStates
    where newStates         = (filter (not.isQueued) $ filter (not.isVisited) $ map mkStates $ mkEdges key curr) ++ rest 
          mkStates s        = (s, steps+1, Map.insert curr True visited)
          isVisited (s,_,_) = Map.member s visited
          isQueued  (s,_,_) = elem s $ map (\(x,_,_) -> x) t

-- Calculate the number of reachable nodes from a starting position
bfsReachableLocations :: Int -> [(Int, Index)] -> [Index] -> Int 
bfsReachableLocations key a@((lim,curr):rest) visited | lim <  0  = 0 
                                                      | otherwise = 1 + bfsReachableLocations key newNodes (visited++[curr])
    where neighbours = filter (not.isQueued) $ filter (not.(\x -> elem x visited)) $ mkEdges key curr
          isQueued n = elem n $ map (\(_,x) -> x) a
          newNodes   = rest ++ map (\x -> (lim-1, x)) neighbours

main = do 
    print $ bfsPathLength           1362 (31,39) [((1,1), 0, Map.empty)]
    print $ bfsReachableLocations   1362 [(50, (1,1))] []
```

The code is not as readable as I'd like. There are probably easier ways of performing some of the steps that I have no yet encountered on my short Haskell journey. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## General Comments

> ```
> mkEdges
> ```

I would probably just call this function `edges`.  `mk` (which I assume is short for `make`) has an imperative ring to it.

> ```
> bfsPathLength :: Int -> Index -> [State] -> Int
> ```

You are forcing users of `bfsPathLength` to pass an initial state.  This forces them to be aware of the internal details of the algorithm, which is not a good design.  You could get rid of the `[State]` parameter and have `bfsPathLength` delegate to a helper function that takes the initial state.  Public interfaces should never expose details that aren't necessary.

> ```
> bfsReachableLocations :: Int -> [(Int, Index)] -> [Index] -> Int
> ```

- What's the purpose of this function?  It doesn't appear to be used for computation of the actual answer to the riddle.  If it's for debugging purposes, you should add a comment that says so (be sure to include *what* it actually does, and *why* it's useful for debugging as well).
- Also, once again you force users to incorporate knowledge about the internal state of the algorithm.

## Performance

You perform a linear search for nodes in the queue and the `visited` set.  You should use a more appropriate datastructure, such as a set, that can do the search in \$O(\log{n})\$, or even \$O(1)\$, time.

## Abstraction

- Consider separating the graph generation from the search algorithm.  This will allow you to use BFS search to solve other problems.  You have some options here, including:

  1. Turn `mkEdges` into a parameter to the search function.
  2. Use a `typeclass`.

  For example, if you turn `mkEdges` into a parameter (and remove the internal state parameter), `bfsPathLength` might have the following type signature:

  ```
  bfsPathLength :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> Int 
  bfsPathLength edgeGenerator goalLocation = ...
  ```
- You should parameterize the start location:

  ```
  bfsPathLength :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> a -> Int
  bfsPathLength edgeGnerator startLocation goalLocation = ...
  ```
- It seems like it would be useful to be able to find the actual path in most cases, rather than just the length:

  ```
  bfsPath :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> [a]
  ```

  Then you can write `bfsPathLength` as follows:

  ```
  bfsPathLength :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> a-> Int
  bfsPathLength edgeGenerator startLocation = length . (bfsPath edgeGenerator startLocation)
  ```